# How do I get the name of the request's content file from a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

In my SiteMaster.cs file I have the following snippet:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageName.Text = this.Page.ToString().Substring(4, this.Page.ToString().Substring(4).Length - 5) + ".aspx";
}
```

The idea with this is on my SiteMaster I can display the current file name by using:

```
<asp:Label ID="pageName" runat="server" />
```

However, I'd like to use pageName in an if statement.
For example, like this

```
if (pageName == 'default.aspx') 
Then  Response.Write ("test") 
End if //pseudo code
```

Is this possible or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Use Request.FilePath to get current file name

Comment: Many thanks Govind. How do I then use this in an if statement to check what page the user is on? Apologies I'm very new to .NET and taking over an existing project. Thank you

Comment: see my answer for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for retrieving Current page name from master page like

```
String pageName  = Request.FilePath;

//return like that /example.aspx

if (pageName == "/default.aspx") 
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: Ooops. Tiny error for the if statement.... `Too many characters in character literal` Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect. Yes, I just figured this out after giving it a shot. Many, many thanks Govind. I really appreciate. Respect from Scotland :D

Comment: Do you know why you were getting "Too many characters in character literal"? Do you know the difference between a character and a string? I think you need to hit some of the .NET C# 101 tutorials out there.

Comment: Hi Ben. Yes, I know the difference between a character and string but wasn't sure why I was getting the error by using single quotes. Can you explain? Will take a look at the tuts too. Thanks :)